# https traffic though a proxy squid/ha/nginx pass through

Tags: windows, reverse-proxy, url-routing, squid, netscaler

I have a set of Windows servers and I want to route https traffic though a proxy to hit my netscaler where I have my certificates.

For example ,

Windows machine-> proxy -> netscaler {certificates}.

I used squid proxy but I get "can't connect securely to this page"

I have tried the following...

Windows machine 10.0.0.1

Proxy machine 10.0.0.2

Netscaler 101.0.0.3

If i try to hit (https://someurl.com 10.0.0.3) from the proxy machine (10.0.0.3) , the url resolves.

If I try to hit https://someurl.com 10.0.0.3 from the windows machine , having configured the lan settings to 10.0.0.2 , it says "can't connect securely to this page"

I used squid proxy.

I was hoping the squid proxy would push the connection to the netscaler ? I don't want to have certificates installed on the middle proxy.

Am I using the wrong type of proxy ? Could someone point me to a guide or give me some hints please